# Remotely authenticate into ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, post

I'm trying to remotely log into some ASP.NET page with username and password. 
I was trying to do it by creating **HttpWebRequest** object and send it with parameters using POST method, but with no success.

Is there any other way? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong, could someone post example here? 
The page I am trying to access is ASP.NET WebForms page (with postbacks and stuff).

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you include more detail? Some code?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what type of authentication you are using. If you are using basic or NTLM authentication, you set the [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx) property of the HttpWebRequest. Using `request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` usually works. The example on the previous link should get you started.

If you are using Forms authentication, it depends on the design of your login page. It may be easier to create a web method you pass the credentials to which returns a cookie of the correct format (or whatever you use for subsequent authentication).

As usual, remember that passing credentials unencrypted (e.g. basic authentication or forms authentication using the idea suggest above) allows an malicious user to sniff the credentials off the network.